# Terraform init command not working in visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

terraform : The term 'terraform' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or
operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct
and try again.
At line:1 char:1

- terraform init
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (terraform:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
  ```

Comment: Which OS? Did you change the path? Did you restart VS Code? https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/terraform/install-cli

Comment: It sounds like it's Windows, so make sure that the terraform binary is somewhere in your path.

Comment: It looks like Windows and the `terraform` binary location might not be in your path variable as everyone has guessed already. Try to follow these steps mentioned in this article https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/94933-how-do-i-edit-my-system-path-in-windows

Answer (score 0):

You can refer this [link](https://kerneltalks.com/cloud-services/configuring-visual-studio-code-for-terraform-to-work-with-aws/).

- Install Terraform
- Install Terraform Visual Studio Code extension

Or you can try using Linux WSL for windows.

Answer (score 0):

If you have downloaded it in the windows system then try to login with the administrator on visual code and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed the terraform. Make sure you add the path to the environment variable. Type in search >> Env > Environment Variables >> System Variables >> Select Path and edit. Add the path to your Terraform application which you have downloaded. Reboot the system. That's it. try again

Answer (score 0):

Download the latest terraform software and install it on your machine. For windows, keep terraform.exe downloaded from this page in C:\Windows\System32 and that should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

**Install Terraform:**

Download the appropriate version of Terraform for your operating system from the official website: Terraform Downloads.
Install Terraform by following the installation instructions for your operating system.

**Add Terraform to the PATH:**

After installing Terraform, you need to ensure that the directory containing the terraform executable is in your system's PATH. This allows you to run the terraform command from any location in the terminal.

```
$env:Path += ";<path-to-terraform>"
```